# Existing game to virtual reality game?

Tags: 3d, virtual-reality

What kind of existing game can be taken as a good source for a 'virtual reality' game, specifically, the one you can play with any 3D VR glasses?

Why do you think this particular game or these games can be adjusted well in the new realm?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I think this question may be too broad or opinion-based as currently phrased. There's no objective answer for what a "good" game for VR is - I've even seen 2D games like Paperboy or Tetris adapted effectively! Even the strengths & weaknesses we know so far in VR aren't universal - I have no problem playing VR flight sims, while some of my friends get simulation sickness as soon as the camera moves - so what's a good game for me isn't necessarily so for them. Can you edit your question to add more specific criteria to help narrow this down to something more concretely answerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racing games are a good waypoint for VR. You don´t have to move, all you need to do is sit and grab a wheel, so the immersion is a lot better than, for example, a shooter.

I am talking about simulation racing games, [LFS](https://www.lfs.net/), for example, not arcades like Gran Turismo or Need For Speed, those games are fine too, but we want immersion and Virtual REALITY.

**Update**: I just found a video showing [LFS on VR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeKjVWIbwzE).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please suggest games that can also add interactive elements in virtual reality? Suppose that the user can only use glasses without any hand controllers.

Comment: I don´t know any specific games, but I can think of mechanics, like dodging, for example, you only need the VR glasses for a dodging game. (Matrix VR: The Game, I would pay a lot for that xD)